# Getting the total size of my five largest files in bash

Tags: bash, find, ls, du

I am trying to get the total size of my five largest files found in a directory but I am not getting du to work on my list. I have two ways of finding and sorting, the five largest files.

```
#!/bin/bash

DIR=$1 #The starting directory path


if [ ! -d "$DIR" ]; then #if the directory is not found
    echo "The directory doesn't exist!" 
    exit 1
fi

echo "Five largest files using ls are:"
test_ls=$( ls -lhR "$DIR" | grep '^-' | sort -r -k 5 -h | head -n 5 )
du -ch "$test_ls"


echo "Five largest files using find/DU are:"
test_find=$( find "$DIR" -type f -exec du -ch {} + | sort -rh | head -n 5 )
du -ch "$test_find"

echo "Total number of files: "
ls -lhR "$DIR" | grep '^-' | wc -l
echo "Total size of files: "
du -sh "$DIR" | awk '{print $1}'
```

If I apply du on the ls variable I get :

```
du: invalid option -- 'r'
du: invalid option -- 'w'
du: invalid option -- '-'
du: invalid option -- 'r'
```

and if I apply it on the find variable I get this for each of the five files

```
du: cannot access '429M': No such file or directory
```

Both the ls version and find version works fine for listing the five largest files under the given directory, but I am relly lost in how I could add their sizes together.

Comment: Does it have to be bash? The zsh shell for example can sort and select files by size directly ex. `du -hc **/*(.NDOL[1,5])`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how best to fix your code, I would propose a different approach without the need for `du` as `find` can return file sizes with `-printf '%s'`.

Note also, that [you should never parse `ls`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead) and that `find` unlike `ls` will run recursively if you don't limit that with `-maxdepth` option.

---

This would find the five largest files in a directory and sum its sizes:

```
find "$DIR" -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%s\n' | sort -nr | head -n5 | paste -sd+ | bc | numfmt --to=iec
```

- `find ... -printf '%s\n'` will print file sizes in bytes
- `| sort -nr | head -n5` will find the five largest numbers
- `| paste -sd+` will join the numbers with a plus sign in between them, so it's a mathematic expression
- `| bc`  will run the mathematic expression
- `| numfmt --to=iec` (optional) will convert the size from bytes to human-readable format.

---

To get additional information, you can save `find` output e.g. in an array:

```bsh
DIR=/some/dir
file_sizes=($(find "$DIR" -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%s\n' | sort -nr))

num_files=${#file_sizes[@]}
total_size=$(IFS=+; echo "$((${file_sizes[*]}))" | numfmt --to=iec)
biggest_files=$(IFS=+; echo "$((${file_sizes[*]:0:5}))" | numfmt --to=iec)

printf 'Total number of files: %d\nTotal size of files: %s\nSize of biggest 5: %s\n' $num_files $total_size $biggest_files
```